# Where do I log application-logins in Thinktecture Identity Server v3

Tags: thinktecture-ident-server, thinktecture

We have IdentityServer v3 with a custom UserService that handles two factor auth. We use it for many clients (webapps), and I would like to track the number of logins to the different applications.

I see that `GetProfileDataAsync` is called every time a user navigates to a new client (happens on every tab switch between webapps also). But I'm unable to track what client is actually causing the call.

Are there other places that could be a good fit for logging

- Application (clientid)
- SubjectId

Thanks for any help

Larsi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IdentityServer supports both developer logging and production events. You can turn on event on the IdentityServerOptions - by default the default logging sink is used to output the events.

On github people created an ElasticSearch sink or you can create your own by implementing IEventService